# Why does GCC compiled code fail on modifying a thread_local std::deque?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, deque, thread-local

I have the following simple code:

```
// test.hpp

#pragma once

#include <deque>

struct A {
    static thread_local std::deque<int> g;
};
```

```
// test.cpp

#include "test.hpp"

thread_local std::deque<int> A::g = std::deque<int>();
```

```
// main.cpp

#include "test.hpp"

int main() {
    A::g.emplace_back(0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with Clang, it finished with code 0 and everything is OK. However, if I compile it with GCC, it crashes with SIGSEGV.

A bit of debugging into the GCC STL source code showed me that during `emplace_back`, the internal pointers of the `std::deque` seem to be `NULL`, which causes the failure on an attempt to allocate memory and place the `int` into it.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a GCC bug?

Versions:

- Clang (which produces a working binary): Homebrew clang version 16.0.2
- GCC (which produces a crashing binary): g++-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0) 13.1.0
- OS: macOS Monterey 12.5.1

P.S. Replacing the std::deque with std::vector somehow fixes the problem (GCC-produces binary finishes with code 0)

UPD:

clang compilation:

```bash
clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp test.cpp -o run
```

gcc compilation (both produced executables fail):

```bash
g++-13 -std=c++20 main.cpp test.cpp -o run
```

or

```bash
g++-13 -std=c++20 -pthread -c test.cpp main.cpp && g++-13 -pthread test.o main.o -o run
```

The failure message I am getting:

```
[1]    95879 segmentation fault  ./run
```

Comment: If you Google "gcc static thread_local crash" you will find a lot of similar questions on SO. Try to make `g` a global variable in .cpp.

Comment: What is the crash _stack trace_ ? What is the _actual_ compile line? Does the crash go away if you use `-pthread` at compile and link time?

Comment: @273K Yeah, I have seen those and indeed your proposed solution works, but I was wondering why my code fails though it seems fine

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have edited the question to add the compile commands and the error message, please see above, the `-pthread` flag did not help:(

Comment: `-pthread` is not needed in new GCC anymore.

Comment: I have also seen a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719784/thread-local-static-member-template-definition-initialisation-fails-with-gcc, but there the author says that removing a template parameter (which I do not have here) fixes the problem. The author went on and submitted a bug report for gcc-8 which still does not seem to be fixed, so it may be a similar issue